# Passing parameters using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass parameters using link_to with ruby on rails, but it says the id parameter I'm sending is null.
code from where I'm sending the id.

```
<% @conference.papers.each do |paper| %>
 <tr>
   <td><%= paper.title %></td>
   <td><%= paper.author %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Download Paper", paper.attachment_url %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Reviews', paper %></td>
    <% if (paper.accepted) %>
        <td><%= "Accepted" %></td>
    <% else %>
        <td><%= "Not accepted" %></td>
    <% end %>
    <% if (@state1 && paper.accepted == false) %>
    <td><%= button_to "Accept",  accept_paper_path(id: paper.id), class: "btn btn-danger", data: { confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to accept #{paper.title}?"} %></td>
    <% end %>
    <% if (@state2) %>
    <% session["a"] = paper.id %>
    <td><%= link_to "Review paper", new_review_path(id: paper) %></td>
    <% end %>

 </tr>
<% end %>
```

code for the review controller

```
  def new
@paper = Paper.find_by_id(params[:id])

@review = Review.new()
```

end

Answer (score 0):

You missed `.id` in

```
link_to "Review paper", new_review_path(id: paper.id)
```

But it is not a good solution. If your `Paper` model `has_many :reviews`, it would be better to nest `reviews` routes in `paper`'s ones. Like this:

```
# config/routes.rb

resources :papers do
  resources :reviews
end
```

And so, your `link_to` will look like:

```
link_to "Review paper", new_paper_review_path(paper)
```

which will generate

> /papers/:paper_id/reviews/new

You can learn more about Rails routing [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: Omitting the id actually does not matter since rails calls `.to_param` on the model. The results of `paper_path(paper)`,  `paper_path(id: paper)` and `paper_path(id: paper.id)` are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start by setting up the routes properly:

```
resouces :papers do
  member do 
    patch :accept
  end
end
```

This will let you accept a review by `PATCH /papers/:id`. To create the button use:

```
<%= button_to accept_paper_path(paper), method: :patch %>
```

Note that this should use the `PATCH` or `PUT` http method - not `GET` since it is a non-idempotent action.

Note that you can just pass the model instead of doing `accept_paper_path(id: model)` or `accept_paper_path(id: model.id)`.

For reviews you will want to create what is called a [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
resouces :papers do
  member do 
    patch :accept
  end
  resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

This gives you the route `/papers/:paper_id/reviews/new`.

```
<%= link_to "Review paper", new_paper_review_path(paper) %>
```

To set the form to create a new review to the use correct path use an array containing the parent and child:

```
<%= form_for([@paper, @review]) %>
```